# How to add button to custom notification and respond to the button accordingly?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I'm using `UNNotificationContentExtension` and trying to figure out how to add button inside my view and have a IBAction for that button in my extension class?

Please see attachment image:

[image]

As you can see I have added two buttons to the `UNNotificationContentExtension` class but the never get called?

This is how I set up notification in my app delegate:

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert]

center.requestAuthorization(options: options) { (authorized, error) in
    if authorized {
        let categoryId = "com.tutplus.Custom-Notification-Interface.notification"

        let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: categoryId, actions: [], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
        center.setNotificationCategories([category])

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 30, repeats: false)
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.categoryIdentifier = categoryId
        content.title = "Notification Title"
        content.subtitle = "Notification Subtitle"
        content.body = "Notification body text"
        content.userInfo = ["customNumber": 100]

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "exampleNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }
}

return true
```

}

**I don't want to add these to `UNNotificationAction` like this way**:

```
let ok = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "OKIdentifier",
                              title: "Turn off", options: [.destructive])
```

I need to have the buttons inside the view and react to them accordingly. I appreciate if any one can help me with that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50575558/ios-notification-content-extension-add-buttons-in-storyboard-and-handle-the-cli You can refer to this question