# IOS notification content extension: add buttons in storyboard and handle the click action

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushviewcontroller

IOS notification content extension: add buttons in MainInterface.storyboard and handle the click action without dismissing the notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after making some research I discover that:
can not handle buttons clicks in the IOS notification content extension, only the type of button can be used is the media button, see the IOS documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/unnotificationcontentextension

Comment: starting from iOS 12, your extensions can have much richer content in the extensions. See this moment from [WWDC2018: What’s New in User Notifications
(https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/710/?time=491)

Answer (score 0):

The up answer is not correct, you can just add UNNotificationExtensionUserInteractionEnabled YES to the info.plist, then you can do every thing just like a common viewController

Answer (score 0):

As [Abdullah S. Al-Hallak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8495794/abdullah-s-al-hallak) said, it is not possible to perform actions that will lunch a certain screen. In [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/unnotificationcontentextension), it is mentioned that "Do not install gesture recognizers or rely on touch events in your interface."

The only possible way is to add actions that will do some things in the presented notification only (like animation, as presented in this cool post: [Adding a Custom UI and Interactivity in Local and Push Notifications](https://www.appcoda.com/user-notifications-ios12/))